# Xcode 6 Swift: Trying to reset IBOutlets in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Using Xcode 6.0.1 w/Swift I've created a label in my storyboard and connected it to ViewController.swift resulting in:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
```

Whenever my app enters the foreground I want to reset myLabel.text to a certain string, say "Hello World".

Previously in Objective-C I could do this in the AppDelegate like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
self.viewController.myLabel.text=@"Hello World";
}
```

But I'm struggling to get this working in Xcode 6 in Swift. Because the AppDelegate doesn't set up an instance of the view controller, I defined that in the AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var vc: ViewController=ViewController()
```

Then tried the same approach:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    vc.myLabel.text="Hello World"
}
```

But when I run the app the view shows up fine, then I hit Home, and then go back into the app, and then I get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

So I understand the UILabel is an optional and I'm getting this error because its value is nil. But I don't understand why its value is nil since the view was already loaded. I've tried using applicationDidBecomeActive with the same result. I can't use viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear in my ViewController class because those methods are not called when the app moves from the background to foreground state.

Also updated this to

```
    if vc.myLabel != nil {
        vc.myLabel.text="Hello World"
    }
```

and sure enough the if statement is false.

Any ideas how to reset UI elements in Xcode 6 and Swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this line -

```
var vc: ViewController=ViewController()
```

allocates a new instance of `ViewController`.  It does not provide a reference to the instance that is displayed from your storyboard, and as this instance is not initialised from a storyboard scene, so all of the `IBOutlet`s are nil.

I would suggest you decouple your app delegate and your view controller and take advantage of the 
`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.

Somewhere in your initialisation of your view controller add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "enterForeground", name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

and then declare a function to handle the event

```
func enterForeground {
   self.myLabel.text="Hello world"
}
```

Comment: I thought that line might be my problem. I was trying to duplicate what the AppDelegate had in earlier versions. In the .h it declared the instance @property (strong, nonatomic) MADViewController *viewController; but in the .m it added it as the rootViewController. I tried to just access the rootViewController in the AppDelegate but couldn't get that to work. I will try your suggestion but I'd love to see if there's a way to do it without notifications. Thanks.

Comment: You can get a reference to the actual view controller using `application.keyWindow.rootViewController` but the event approach is arguably 'better' as it decouples your app delegate and your view controller.  It also makes it simple for multiple view controllers to respond to a return to foreground

Comment: `application.keyWindow.rootViewController.myLabel.text="Hello World" ` doesn't work, it can't find myLabel on the rootViewController. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to cast `rootViewController` to an instance of  `ViewController` as a plain `UIViewController` doesn't know about `myLabel`. I.e. `let vc=application.keyWindow.rootViewController as ViewController; vc.myLabel.text="hello world"`

Comment: Yeah, that was it, thanks so much @Paulw11. I guess that's what I get for not reading the whole Swift programming guide. Got stalled at ARC :-)